# Better WP Security : dashboard doesn't work any more

Tags: plugins

Just installed Better WP Security (with File Change Detection feature activated), then logged out. Now wp-login.php is blank with the message :

Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 93 bytes in /home4/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/better-wp-security/inc/secure.php on line 20

What can I do do access the dashboard again?

Comment: Please note, that the user [already had an infected site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/90011/overwhelming-code-injection) and that there could be a relation between those two answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rename the directory in which the plugin resides to disable it

Comment: This answer was "automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content". It is a plausible solution but a more detailed answer would be nice.

Comment: LOL. Guess 2 will not be a good answer to how much is 1 plus 1 ;)

Comment: Yes, I know. Some questions beg for short answers. (toscho has called me on it). Still, if the question were asked on this forum "2" would not be a good answer since answers are expected to be explanations and not just raw solutions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question

Comment: Well good answer or not it did the trick and I'm cool with that! It works after I disabled File Change Detection in the plugin. Looks like this feature can have nasty consequences.

Comment: I thought that "... to disable it" part was a good explanation. ok, enough meta on this, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You might try adding `define('WP_DEBUG', false);` to your wp-config.php file, but that might not do it, and you really should probably uninstall that plugin, because it doesn't really give you better security (it does give some good suggestions though), and if it is messing up your login... well scrap it.

To uninstall the plugin without access to your dashboard:

1. Use your FTP program to navigate to "/home4/mysite/public_html/wp-content/plugins/".
2. Rename or remove the "better-wp-security" folder (I would remove it).

Then you should be able to log in again.